# Unpredictable behaviour of top-fixed navbars on iOS with input fields and labels

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, mobile-webkit

I'm having a website with fixed top 'navbar', along with few input fields and labels "for" them.
Clicking on labels, creates focus on corresponding inputs with no any side-effects to the rest of the page. (I've tested it out on all modern desktop browsers and android's native browser and also chrome).

All is fine except on iOS (iPad, iPhone), where clicking on same label makes:
input to focus (which is expected) and sliding in soft-keyboard (which is expected).

Now, when I click on label of another input, default scrolling takes place and newly focused input is adjusting its position to stay within visible part of viewport - this is also fine and highly expected behaviour, but at the same time, this causes weird effects to 'navbar' which is fixed to the top. Navbar  clashes all over the viewport without any sense.

I need to add that the same behaviour is not happening when I click on input itself - only when I click on corresponding label.

Has anyone experienced this before? Looks like a bug on iOS, but I'm really wandering - what is the real difference between clicking on label, and clicking on corresponding input and why implementation of this behaviour differs **ONLY** on iOS.

I have temporary workaround to this, by detecting iPod,iPhone,iPad userAgent and removing "for" attribute from labels on these agents (I want to retain 'clickability' of labels where possible), but it doesn't seems to be right for me.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: which version of iOS really depends too... 

iOS 5 and Android 4 both have position:fixed support. Can you provide the markup and css?

Comment: I've done tests on iPad2 with iOS 7.1.2, also tested on iPhone5 with iOS 8, with the same output. I'll update when I create some testing fiddle, but this is happening on pages with fixed element, and form containing many label-input pairs.

Comment: ok dok. So I got [link](http://goo.gl/lUPsaO) little test page which should simulate my scenario. You'll see what I mean when you open it up in iOS device - just click on input labels and observe navbar

Comment: try changing it to position absolute instead of position fixed

Comment: @cport1 - thanks, but I need it to always stay atttached to the top of viewport

Answer (score 0):

U can replace the css position attribute of navbar from "fixed" to "absolute", and switch the unit of width & height from "%" or "px" to "vh" or "vw" then it would goes well on ios.